# To find subspace of $R^3$ generated by a subset.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am supposed to find the subspace of $R^3$ generated by

$S = \{(x,y,z)\in R^3 : y=x^2 \}$ and to find a basis of this subspace.

I was trying to find out some linearly independent elements belonging to the set $S$. I am unable to find a general approach to deal with such kind of problem. Kindly help. Any hint will be of great help to me. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: If you find three linearly independent vectors in $S$ you know it must generate everything. Note that $S$ itself is far from linear and thus $S$ itself is not a vector space. Luckily, you are looking at the subspace generated by the elements of $S$.

Answer (score 3):

$(1,1,0), (1,1,1), (2,4,0)$ are LI elements in this space so the subspace generated is $\mathbb R^{3}$.

Comment: Is there any general method to solve these kinda problems????

Comment: How to guess that these are the points? Is there any general way of thinking to find the solution to these types of problems?